# Manipulating x axis labelling for a feather plot

Tags: r, plot

I have some wind speed and direction data over a course of some time and I need to plot it into a feather plot.

After surfing the web for some time, I find a function someone wrote to plot the feather plot that works for me (Thank you if you are reading this!!). My problem now is that I don't know how to manipulate the labelling of the x-axis.

After the plotting, the figure looks like this:
[image]
Now the x-axis doesn't look too bad here, but imagine I have 200 data points (and thus ticks) instead of 10, and the axis ticks can get a bit confusing. So I was hoping someone can help me manipulate the x-axis, specifically messing with the ticks.

The code to plot the figure is:

```
stg <- scan(what="", sep="\n")
9/20/15_12:00   2.597058824 157.9411765
9/21/15_0:00    2.177192982 185.1754386
9/21/15_12:00   2.577391304 189.2173913
9/22/15_0:00    1.984955752 237.4336283
9/22/15_12:00   3.993859649 252.6315789
9/23/15_0:00    1.613392857 175.5357143
9/23/15_12:00   3.849166667 216.8333333
9/24/15_0:00    2.138135593 117.0338983
9/24/15_12:00   3.32605042  216.302521
9/25/15_0:00    1.490178571 239.8214286

df <- read.table(textConnection(stg), sep="")
colnames(df) <- c("Time", "wsp", "wdir")

df$PTime <- as.POSIXct(df$Time, format="%m/%d/%y_%H:%M")

feather.plot2 <- function (r, theta, xpos, yref = 0, use.arrows = TRUE, col.refline = "lightgray",
      fp.type = "s", main = "", xlab = "", ylab = "", xlabels = NULL,
      ...)
  {
      if (missing(xpos))
          xpos <- 1:length(theta)
      if (fp.type == "m")
          theta <- 5 * pi/2 - theta
      x <- r * cos(theta)
      y <- r * sin(theta)
      xmult <- diff(range(xpos))/(diff(range(y)) * 2)
      x <- x * xmult
      xlim <- range(c(xpos, x + xpos))
      ylim <- range(c(y, yref))
      oldpin <- par("pin")
      xdiff <- xlim[2] - xlim[1]
      ydiff <- ylim[2] - ylim[1]
      plot(0, xlim = xlim, ylim = ylim, type = "n", main = main,
          xlab = xlab, ylab = ylab, axes = TRUE, xaxt = "n")
      box()
      if (is.null(xlabels))
          axis(1)
      else axis(1, at = xpos, labels = xlabels)
      abline(h = yref, col = col.refline)
      if (use.arrows)
          arrows(xpos, yref, xpos + x, y, length = 0.1, ...)
      else segments(xpos, yref, xpos + x, y, ...)
      par(pin = oldpin)
  }

feather.plot2(df$wsp, df$wdir, fp.type="m", xlabels=df$PTime)
```

And what I want is something like having big ticks for 12:00, and smaller ticks for 0:00, like in this figure:
[image]

Although I don't know why the label for this figure comes out as "Sun - Thu" instead of dates...

The code for this figure is:

```
daterange=c(min(df$PTime), max(df$PTime))

plot(x=df$PTime, y=df$wsp, xaxt="n", type="l")
axis.POSIXct(1, at=seq(daterange[1], daterange[2], by="day"))
axis.POSIXct(1, at=seq(daterange[1], daterange[2], by="12 hours"), tcl = -0.3, labels=FALSE )
```

I've tried using using these axis commands on the feather plot, but it did not work. So I'd appreciate any help/advice. Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 1):

I'm seeing two requests: Major and minor ticks;  and More compact axis annotation of date-times. Step 1: Suppress the default axis creation. Step 2: The usual manor is to label the major ticks, so we would determine the proper location of those ticks and give a format specification to the labels. Step 3: place the minor tick marks. Most of this you've already figured out, and I would have thought the format problem was the easiest one to solve, so let's see:

```
plot(x=df$PTime, y=df$wsp, xaxt="n", type="l")
axis.POSIXct(1, at=seq(daterange[1], daterange[2], by="day"), format="%m-%d %H%P",
              lwd.ticks=2)
axis.POSIXct(1, at=seq(daterange[1], daterange[2], by="12 hours"),
              tcl = -0.3, labels=FALSE )
```

[image]

Seems to succeed at what I think are your goals. The use of `by = "day"` may be what leads the interpreter to choose the three letter abbrev of day names. (I don't really know.)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, although my problem is not with the line figure, but the feather plot with the feather.plot2 function. I'd like to manipulate the ticks on that figure, but since I did not write the function and do not understand most of what's going on in the function, I don't know where I could mess around to deal with the ticks

Comment: You actually already had larger and smaller ticks. I added the capacity to make the "bigger" ticks have thicker lines. What more do you mean by "manipulate the ticks". The phrase didn't only indicated to your audience that something is not what you what but is gives no positive guidance.

Comment: I mean that my problem is not with the second line figure, but the first feather plot. The second figure was posted as an example for what I want the ticks for the first figure to look like, but the commands I posted for changing the ticks do not work on the feather plot, which was plotted with the function I posted in the first code section